# add hidden information to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way in code to add some hidden information to a UITableViewCell?

Use Case:

- In an activity feed, `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called and each cell has one activity.  Each its own unique "activityId".
- Each cell has some buttons in them (with unique tags) and, when pressed, the given activity is "liked"
- Each button has an IBOutlet, which would then call the model to then process the like

The code I have for the IBOutlet is:

```
- (IBAction)buttonUp:(UIButton *)sender {

UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[btn superview] superview];

UIView *cellView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag: ..myUniqueButtonTag.. ];

NSLog(@"activityId is: %@", ...);
}
```

Comment: use cell.accessibilityValue and assign data to it.. when click find that cell and its accessibilityValue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create a custom UITableViewCell class if you want to do more complex things in your cells then the standard ones allow - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: The only thing I really need is the activityId... would I really need a whole new subclass for that?

Comment: Well maybe you could use the tag property if your id is a NSNumber. But subclassing UITableViewCell would be easy if all you really need to do is to add a property. And it might be useful to have a subclass in the future if you want to extend what it will do.

Comment: which I will probably want to (well, will need to, actually).  So, this seems the best course of action.  Off the top of your head, know of any large pitfalls I should avoid when setting it up?  EDIT: will accept this answer as correct after time limit

Comment: The auto layout can get a bit tricky I've found - look at this answer and the github project for an example of custom cells with variable height.  I found it helpful. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/3096507

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do the `superview shuffle`: `[[btn superview] superview]` because it will break sooner or later.

I agree with @ansible that you should create a custom cell and use a delegate relationship so the button tells the cell it is tapped and the cell tells the delegate. This is the best and most appropriate solution.

For cheaters though, consider using `objc_setAssociatedObject` on the button to associate the id info with it so that you can access it in the action method.

Comment: I've gone ahead and made a custom cell, but when the button is pressed I rely on `[[[btn superview] superview] superview]` to get the custom cell's class.  Regarding your first sentence, is there a better way?

Comment: Make the cell the target of the button method and have it forward the action.